# How to execute large sql query in magento?

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to store huge content in db and my sample text is 16129 characters in length when i tried to execute this query it is showing "error:The requested URL could not be retrieved" in firefox and "no-data received" in chrome.

Moreover I use `LONGTEXT` as datatype for text in DB.

I also tried to execute the query directly in phpmyadmin it is working correctly.

The code is shown below.

```
public function _getConnection($type = 'core_write') {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
    }

public function testdbAction(){
        $db = $this->_getConnection();
        $current_time=now();
        $text="The European languages are members of the same family......  ...Europe uses the same vocabulary. The ";//text is 16129 characters in length
        $sql = "INSERT into test(`usercontent_id`,`app_id`,`module_id`,`customer_id`,`content`,`created_time`,`updated_time`,`item_id`,`index_id`,`position_id`) VALUES (NULL, 15, 9,2,'" .$text. "','" . $current_time . "','" . $current_time . "',1003,5,4)";
        $db->query($sql);        
    }
```

How do i handle this? any suggestions or help..

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: It looks like you're running this in a controller since you have testdbAction().  If so, what do you have as the output?  What happens if you replace your testdbAction() function contents with an echo?

Comment: i tried it by running huge content and run the query using this $db->query($sql);  But magento could not run it. IT goes "The requested URL could not be retrieved".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$db->exec($sql)` instead of `$db->query($sql)`

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating with database structure and data Magento has a dedicated place. It is called install / upgrade scripts. It was made to keep track of modules version for easy updates. So you should use a script to add new data.

Here's an example.

config.xml of your module:

```
<modules>
    <My_Module>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </My_Module>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <my_module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>My_Module</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
         </my_module_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Now, you need to create following file:

`My_Module/sql/my_module_setup/install-0.0.1.php`

Now, depending on your Magento version, file would need to have a different name. If you're using Magento CE 1.4 or lower (EE 1.8) then you should name it `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`.

This script will be launched at next website request. Class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` will execute code inside `install-0.0.1.php`. From within the install script you will have access to the Setup class by using `$this` object;

So now, you can write in script following code:

```
$this->startSetup();

$text = <<<TEXT
YOUR LONG TEXT GOES HERE
TEXT;

$this->getConnection()
    ->insert(
        $this->getTable('test'),
        array(       
             'usercontent_id' => null,
             'app_id' => 15,
             'content' => $text,
             //other fields in the same fashion
        )
    );

$this->endSetup();
```

And that's it. It's a clean and appropriate way of adding custom data to the database in Magento.

If you want to save a user input on a regular basis using forms, then I recommend creating w model, resource model and collection, define entities in config.xml. For more information please refer to Alan Storm's articles, like [this one](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm).

I hope that I understood your question correctly.